# Push smart contract on Remix IDE (online) to github

Tags: blockchain, solidity

How can I push my work on Remix IDE (online) to github? How is it possible? Is there any plug-in or something? I am a Windows user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a git plugin of Remix, you can activate it, then configure the git and enjoy.

[image]

Comment: @AimenAhmad if the answer is helpful, would you please accept the answer so other people can reach it later?

Comment: Yes, It is helpful. Marked!

Answer (score 0):

I like to connect Remix to my local file system, and then commit to Github as I normally do.

First step is click on the workspace dropdown in Remix, and then click "connect to localhost":

[image]

A dialog will show, giving instructions on how to connect to localhost, but essentially the two main steps are:

**1.** Install Remixd npm package using `npm install -g @remix-project/remixd`

**2.** Execute the command `remixd -s <path-to-the-shared-folder> -u <remix-ide-instance-URL>`

Then, whatever you write in Remix will automatically be synced with your local folder. From here you can commit to Github as you would normally.